# Creating datetime for ebay with php

Tags: php, datetime, ebay-api

I cannot create a valid datetime with php for ebay finding api.

According to their [api](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/CallRef/types/simpleTypes.html#dateTime), the datetime value should look like this

2004-08-04T19:09:02.768Z

I found in the php documentation that there is a special notation for ISO 8601 with `(new DateTime())->format('c')` but it does not give me the correct date.

Anyone know how to create one?

Comment: Try `(new DateTime())->format(DateTime::ISO8601);`, what does it return ?

Comment: It returns 2016-10-08T10:43:20+0000 but that is not a valid datetime for ebay.

Comment: Yes, actually as mentioned in the API the date should be in UTC (Zulu time, no timezone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This:

```
<?php
    $time = microtime(true);
    $tMicro = sprintf("%03d",($time - floor($time)) * 1000);
    $tUtc = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.', $time).$tMicro.'Z';
    echo $tUtc;
?>
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot.